# PHP XPath - query finds too many nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to multiplicate a row (with `data-id='first'`) from a template three times and fill the proper field (`{first}`) with some value (0,1,2 in this case). Below you can find my simple code. I don't understand, why this line - `$nodeList = $xpath->query("//*[text()[contains(.,'first')]]", $newNode);` finds more than one node (it finds nodes which contain text 'first'). It just finds both rows - the cloned and the original one, so it replaces the text in both of them, while it should replace it only in the new one - please note that I'm providing the second parameter for function `$xpath->query` which should make the search relative to just that new node I just cloned.

Here's a fiddle: https://eval.in/170941

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr data-id="first">
                <td>{first}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$element = $xpath->query("//*[@data-id='first']")->item(0);
$element->removeAttribute("data-id");

$parent = $element->parentNode;

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

    $newNode = $element->cloneNode(true);

    $parent->insertBefore($newNode, $element);

    $nodeList = $xpath->query("//*[text()[contains(.,'first')]]", $newNode);

    for($j = 0; $j < $nodeList->length; $j++) {
        $n = $nodeList->item($j);
        $n->nodeValue = preg_replace("{{first}}", $i, $n->nodeValue);
    }

}

$parent->removeChild($element);



echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

As you can see, the result is a three elements table with rows valued 0,0,0, while expected values should be 0,1,2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting an xpath location path with `/` means  tha it start at the document root. So `//*` is always any element node, the context argument has no effect.

Try:

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query(".//*[text()[contains(.,'first')]]", $newNode);
```

HINT: DOMXpath::query() does only allow expressions that return a node list, DOMXpath::evaluate() allows all expressions. Example: `count(//*)`.

HINT: DOMNodelist objects implement iterator, you can use foreach to iterate them.

Comment: I consider your answer as the good one, because you really pointed out what I was doing wrong - Didn't know about the location path! Thank you very much, I was worried yesterday that I wasted my whole day on this :P But it seems that it was just my lack of knowledge about xpath. Thanks!
About query and evaluate and iterator - I know these things, but thanks either way :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are cloning the original node, but in your first pass you're altering the original node's content.  Every pass after that is copying the already modified node, so there is no `{first}` to find.

One solution is to make a clone of the source element which you never insert into the document, and use that inside your loop.

Here's my fiddle: https://eval.in/171149

```
<?php

$html = '<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><table><tr data-id="first"><td>{first}</td></tr></table></body></html>';


$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$element = $xpath->query("//*[@data-id='first']")->item(0);
$element->removeAttribute("data-id");

$parent = $element->parentNode;
$clonedNode = $element->cloneNode(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

    $newNode = $clonedNode->cloneNode(true);

    $parent->insertBefore($newNode, $element);

    $nodeList = $xpath->query("//*[text()[contains(.,'first')]]", $newNode);

    for($j = 0; $j < $nodeList->length; $j++) {
        $n = $nodeList->item($j);
        $n->nodeValue = preg_replace("{{first}}", $i, $n->nodeValue);
    }

}

$parent->removeChild($element);



echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: oh wow, that's clever! Although it doesn't solve it exactly the way I wanted, I still plused your answer, but the correct solution should be in @ThW answer. Thanks anyway!